# How to upload file to custom folder and send attachment to email in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, file-upload, attachment

I have a some trouble with understanding in uploading and sending attachment.
For example:

```
$zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$attachments = '';
if (!empty($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
    $path = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    if (copy($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $path)) $attachments = $path;
}

$subject = 'You have message from ' . get_bloginfo('name');
$message = '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Zip Code:</b></td><td>' . $zip_code . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Phone:</b></td><td>' . $phone . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Email:</b></td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Attachments:</b></td><td>' . $attachments . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"" . $attachments . "\"\n\n";
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
```

This code work not correctly. Email and attachment sending correctly, but file upload in root directory. And when I upload the same files, new file overwrite old file. I don't understand how I can add some hash tag to file name.

Maybe U can help me? Any ideas or where I can read how to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is not working? To help you find out what is not working, try this:

```
$zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$attachments = '';
if (!empty($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
    $path = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    if (copy($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $path)) $attachments = $path;
}

$subject = 'You have message from ' . get_bloginfo('name');
$message = '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Zip Code:</b></td><td>' . $zip_code . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Phone:</b></td><td>' . $phone . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Email:</b></td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td width="150px"><b>Attachments:</b></td><td>' . $attachments . '</td></tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"" . $attachments . "\"\n\n";

echo 'Headers:  . $headers . '<br>/r/n';
echo 'To: ' . $to .'<br>/r/n';
echo 'Subject: ' . $subject . '<br>/r/n';
echo 'Message: ' . $message . '<br>/r/n';
echo 'Image: <img src="' . $attachments .'" />';


// $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
```

You'll be able to see what is missing if there is anything missing, and you'll be able to rectify your code this way.

Comment: Mm, email sending work correctly, but attachment upload to root directory. I want to file upload in custom folder, like this `wp-content/upload/attachment/` and add to upload file some hash tag to name like `name_001.doc, name_002.pdf` etc

Comment: To upload the file to the upload file directory, change the `$path = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];` line to

`$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();`
`$path = $upload_dir['path'] . $_FILES['attachment']['name'];`

To include a hash to the file name you'd need a function to split the extension name of the original file and check the directory to see which iteration you're currently at, example `name_017.pdf`, so the function will need to add one, making the new uploaded file name `name_018.pdf`.

Comment: Thank U! U really help me. For current copy I use `$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $path = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $_FILES['attachment']['name'];` and now I try to add hash to file name